# @ResponseBody unable to return XML

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a REST Webservice returning an int via @responseBody and I want this response to be in XML, and I don't know how to achieve that despite many tries.

My controller is as follow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UserByAppli", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Application> getNbUserByAppli()
{
    return this.DAO.getNbUserByAppli();
}
```

And my application Object:

```
@Component
@XmlRootElement(name="Application")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Application
{
    @XmlElement(name="Nom")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="NbUtilisateurs")
    private int nbUsers;

    public Application()
    {

    }
    ...
}
```

It always returns application/json, and when I specify the header "Accept=application/xml" I get a 406 response code with org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation in Spring logs.

An explanation or a search direction would be appreciated...

Comment: You are returning nothing what can be marshalled to XML. The objects of the list can be marshalled to XML but not the list of objects itself. That would need a seperate object. I guess a single `Application` but not your list of applications.

Comment: @M.Deinum It's the same problem if I return a simple int

Comment: An `int` isn't an xml object. To return XML you must return an object that can be marshalled to XML (i.e. your `Application` object which I also mentioned in my previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have JAXB2 in your classpath and have registered the appropriate [message converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html) and pass the `Accept: application/xml` header. Also, like M. Deinum suggested, for the marshalling to work, you also need to wrap the `<Application />` elements in another element `<Applications />`.